# Function to form message from text [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript

UPDATE: Thank you very much for advises! Great community! I specified the task.

I need to write a function, which has two arguments: message, text.
If message could be created from text letters, function should return true. Otherwise, return false.

compose("ohle", "hello"); //should return true

compose("elooooo", "hello"); // should return false, because there is only one "o" in text "hello".

I've tried this:

```
function compose(message, text){
    for(var i = 0, len = message.length; i < len; i++){
        if(text.includes(message[i])){
            console.log(true);
        } else {
            console.log(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Actually, I cannot think what shoud I put in the loop besides console.log or return. But then, it consoles log for each letter.

Do You have some insights? Task should be written in javascript ES5.
Thanks

Comment: You probably meant to return/print false inside the loop if the condition fails, and return/print true after the loop. Think what you wrote though; it will print once per loop, which doesn't seem to be what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Array.prototype.every()` and `.indexOf()`

```js
const compose = (letter, text) => [...text].every(char => letter.indexOf(char) > -1);

console.log(compose("ohle", "hello"));
console.log(compose("elooooo", "hello"));
```

Comment: Check question again, This doesn't provide the answer.

Comment: @Durga Good catch. See updated post. Substituted `text` for `letter` at iterable using the same  pattern.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't returns 7 true, actually your function logs 7 trues. If you want one result you need:

```
function compose(letter, text){
    for(var i = 0, len = letter.length; i < len; i++){
        if(!text.includes(letter[i])){
            return false;
        } 
    }
    return true;
}
```

And then you can console.log result of your function

Comment: Check question again, This doesn't provide the answer.